# Another option of sharing JS code between projects then yarn workspaces (monorepo) or public/private npm package

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I am using `yarn workspaces` for my 4 projects:

- Client web app (React)
- Client mobile app (React Native)
- Server (NestJS)
- Shared (package for shared code)

But there is more problems than benefits in my usecase. For example all packages needs to be set to "nohoist" to work properly and Microsoft's AppCenter have problems with building apps from monorepos.

So I decided to get rid of monorepos, but I do not want to loose my shared package which includes many enums and helpers used across all 3 other projects.

Is there another option of sharing JS code between projects then yarn workspaces (monorepo) or public/private npm packages?

Comment: You could try setting the react native app to use no hoist? `"workspaces": {
    "nohoist": [
      "*",
    ]
  },`

Comment: For reference this would be added to the package.json of the react native package.